# Switching tab in Selenium causes page to reload

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm handling multiple tabs with SeleniumJS. Firstly, it switches to the second tab to handle automation on that, but switching back to the first tab causes the first tab to reload.

My current code of handling it is the standard:

```
if (handles && handles.length >= 2) {
      try {
        await driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);

        console.log("Switched back to the first tab");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error switching back to the first tab:", error);
      }
}
```

I have also tried making it pressing the bind `Ctrl+Tab` but that still reloaded the page.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please share code before and after the condition. Your code looks fine as mentioned below. there might be a line triggering the refresh. We are using the same line but in Java and is working as expected, no refresh. "driver.switchTo().window(...)"